# target encoding gives error Error in l[is.na(l)] <- m : replacement has length zero

Tags: r, function, encoding

I have tried to make a reproducible example although I do not succeed.

I try to do target encoding with the function below from rbloggers:

```
function(x, y, sigma = NULL) {
  d <- aggregate(y, list(factor(x, exclude = NULL)), mean, na.rm = TRUE)
  m <- d[is.na(as.character(d[, 1])), 2]
  l <- d[, 2]
  names(l) <- d[, 1]
  l <- l[x]
  l[is.na(l)] <- m
  if (!is.null(sigma)) {
    l <- l * rnorm(length(l), mean = 1, sd = sigma)
  }
  l
}
```

It runs fine on the example data:

```
data1 <- data.frame(factor_var = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b"),
                    target = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE))
```

which gives:

```
> l
  a   a   a   a   b   b 
0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.0 0.0
```

Although when I apply it to my own dataset it gives the error below:

```
Error in l[is.na(l)] <- m : replacement has length zero
```

The error is thrown by `l[is.na(l)]`

m is " numeric (empty) " although this seems not the cause.

Thanks a lot!

my own data:

```
structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("Albania_Albanian Cup", 
"Albania_Superliga", "Argentina_Copa Argentina", "Argentina_Copa de la Superliga"), class = "factor")
```

Comment: I do not have NA in my data

Comment: > dput(head(y, 20))
c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)

Comment: thanks a lot. I will test it in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be that the factor data may have some levels for which the data is not present, thus

```
l <- l[x]
> l
Argentina_Copa Argentina Argentina_Copa Argentina Argentina_Copa Argentina Argentina_Copa Argentina Argentina_Copa Argentina Argentina_Copa Argentina 
               0.3333333                0.3333333                0.3333333                0.3333333                0.3333333                0.3333333 
Argentina_Copa Argentina                     <NA>                     <NA>                     <NA> 
               0.3333333                       NA                       NA                       NA
```

creates some NA columns for those unused levels.  Instead, we may have to use `droplevels` to remove the unused levels

```
f2 <- function(x, y, sigma = NULL) {
  x <- droplevels(x)
  d <- aggregate(y, list(factor(x, exclude = NULL)), mean, na.rm = TRUE)
  m <- d[is.na(as.character(d[, 1])), 2]
  l <- d[, 2]
  names(l) <- d[, 1]
  l <- l[x]
  l[is.na(l)] <- m
  if (!is.null(sigma)) {
    l <- l * rnorm(length(l), mean = 1, sd = sigma)
  }
  l
}
```

-testing

```
> f2(x, y)
       Albania_Superliga        Albania_Superliga        Albania_Superliga        Albania_Superliga        Albania_Superliga        Albania_Superliga 
               0.7142857                0.7142857                0.7142857                0.7142857                0.7142857                0.7142857 
       Albania_Superliga Argentina_Copa Argentina Argentina_Copa Argentina Argentina_Copa Argentina 
               0.7142857                0.3333333                0.3333333                0.3333333 
# OP's original function

> f1(x, y)
Error in l[is.na(l)] <- m : replacement has length zero
```

---

OR another option is to match with character converted vector instead of factor

```
> l[as.character(x)]
       Albania_Superliga        Albania_Superliga        Albania_Superliga        Albania_Superliga        Albania_Superliga        Albania_Superliga 
               0.7142857                0.7142857                0.7142857                0.7142857                0.7142857                0.7142857 
       Albania_Superliga Argentina_Copa Argentina Argentina_Copa Argentina Argentina_Copa Argentina 
               0.7142857                0.3333333                0.3333333                0.3333333 
> l[x]
Argentina_Copa Argentina Argentina_Copa Argentina Argentina_Copa Argentina Argentina_Copa Argentina Argentina_Copa Argentina Argentina_Copa Argentina 
               0.3333333                0.3333333                0.3333333                0.3333333                0.3333333                0.3333333 
Argentina_Copa Argentina                     <NA>                     <NA>                     <NA> 
               0.3333333                       NA                       NA                       NA 

f3 <- function(x, y, sigma = NULL) {
  d <- aggregate(y, list(factor(x, exclude = NULL)), mean, na.rm = TRUE)
  m <- d[is.na(as.character(d[, 1])), 2]
  l <- d[, 2]
  names(l) <- d[, 1]
  l <- l[as.character(x)]
  l[is.na(l)] <- m
  if (!is.null(sigma)) {
    l <- l * rnorm(length(l), mean = 1, sd = sigma)
  }
  l
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will check if I made a mistake in my code causing the unused levels. It seems the factorlevels are assigned outside the cross-validation, while the encoding is done within the cross-validation. Which seems correct to me since it was intended to prevent overfitting.

Comment: @user2165379 That could be okay, but when you are using `[` with factor having unused levels not matching, it returns those `NA` values as I showed.  Just for the sake of replication, you can use `as.character(x)` as I showed above.  Do you want the output to return all the unused levels as well from aggregate?

Comment: i will do further testing and think it over to see if i need the unused levels. thanks a lot for your solution!